# iPhone 7 (13.4.1) Battery Drain Issue

Tags: iphone, battery

I am facing severe battery drain issue with my iPhone 7 (13.4.1). Battery discharges almost 1%-2% per minute while using. Even though battery capacity shows 100% in **Battery** menu in **Settings**. Additionally I checked with **CoconutBattery** which gives give below results, which seems to be alright. I have disable auto-sync and other general settings as per tips found in web to reduce battery usage. Still why is battery drain happening?

**coconutBattery Output:**

[image]

**Battery Health Output:**

[image]

Comment: Try resetting all of your settings in Settings > General > Reset > Reset All Settings. This will revert all your settings to Factory Defaults. This will not erase any personal data. Another solution might be backing up your data, resetting the iPhone (Erase all Content and Settings), then restoring from the backup.

Comment: Cycle count 11… is this a new battery? If so, is it an Apple battery?

Comment: @Tetsujin I bought it from a shop that sells used iPhones few months back. Battery was already replaced (100% capacity) before I bought.

Comment: I'd take it back then.

Comment: If the only difference is the battery then my guess is the battery is bad.  I agree with @Tetsujin.

Comment: @Tetsujin no option for that. these shops don't provide warranties. :(

Comment: @fsb I am thinking the same. Though will try resetting device first to check again. I bought it as a test device for my apps. That's why didn't bother much before. :/

Comment: @Todd Same problem after resetting all settings.

Comment: @Fida Do you have any apps that could be causing this

Comment: @Fida Was this an Apple Authorized Service Provider? Remember that you should always buy from Apple or an Apple Authorized Service Provider. Please upload a screenshot of your Battery Health screen in Settings on your iPhone. It will say that it can't identify your Battery if it is not Apple. If it was an Apple Authorized Service Provider and you have AppleCare, then you might be able to send it to Apple for servicing.

Comment: @Todd I have upload the battery health screen page image. The shop was just a regular shop in a local supermarket, not authorized. :(

Comment: @Fida If you're willing to pay, then you might be able to service the battery at an Apple Authorized Service Provider or you might be able to get Apple to fix it. It seems like your Battery is from Apple and It is genuine. It might be a used battery so that might be the issue.

Comment: @Fida have you been charging the iPhone with a charger/power adapter that didn't come from Apple (Maybe Tylt, Samsung, etc.)? If so, this can affect battery performance.

Comment: @Todd The charge is from Apple, didn't use any other charger. I guess I will have to replace the battery with an "genune working" one. :/

Comment: @Fida the battery seems genuine and Apple, its just its probably used or has a manufacturing defect :(

Comment: @Todd bad luck... :(